# "How to get query in template from django many to many fields by using parent class??"

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

"I made a parent class model where i put some fields which are related with many to many fields. I want to get all individual data from many to many field using the query of parent class. When i do these i get the all query set of the field.

I tried ,`match = Match.objects.all()` in views function..

then i tried `{{ match.mega_league.pool_price }}` to get the value..but its not working on template...

models:

```
class Match(models.Model): 
    mega_league = models.ManyToManyField('MegaLeague', blank=True)

class MegaLeague(models.Model): 
    price_pool = models.IntegerField() winner = models.IntegerField()
```

views:

```
match = Match.objects.all()
```

templates:

```
{{ match.mega_league.pool_price }}
```

but it's not working..
'''
when i use `{{ match.mega_league.pool_price }}` this give me blank result but in database i have data for price_pool and winner also... i need the individual access for price_pool and winner..."

Comment: @DanielRoseman i use the for loop and i can access all queryset, but from MegaLeague, i can't access price_pool and winner data individually using {{ match.mega_league.pool_price }} and {{ match.mega_league.pool_price }}...without this two i can access every queryset..

Answer (score 0):

`match` is a queryset, a list of all Matches. You need to loop through them. Then for each match, mega_league is *also* a queryset, si you need to iterate through the leagues.

```
<ul>
{% for m in match %}
<li><ul>
{% for league in match.mega_league.all %}
<li>{{ league.pool_price }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: @Deniel Roseman thank you so much..now it's working...in 1st loop it will be '
{% for match in match %}'